# How to add border to a dynamic list of Subreport in Jrxml?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

[Sample report format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRMpR.png)

My report has a subreport which would be dynamic. I need a border around it

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the subreport inside a frame and add borders around the frame.

Comment: I tried this. But if the report contains dynamic subreport, the last page would have frame size border.

Comment: Do you mean that the frame gets printed even if the subreport fetches no data?

Comment: Yes. Even for empty pages border gets printed. I tried with isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" also

Comment: If you can predetermine on the main report whether the subreport will fetch any data, you can use a `printWhenExpression` on the frame. Otherwise, you should add the frame component inside the subreport.